# How to perform a numerical integration (with limits) of discrete data in Python using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, simpsons-rule

I have an experimental time signal, and I need to compute some integral out of it. In detail, I need to compute the PSD, and then compute the power in some bands of frequencies. So, it seems that `scipy` is the best way to compute integrals. But the algorithms `simpson` and `trapezoid` compute for the whole array. There are no integration limits

I can write a function to perform the search of the arrays and get the index of the integration limits, applying then `simpson` to an slice of the original array. But I was wondering if there is any other way.

Thanks

MWE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import welch
from scipy.integrate import simpson

t_0 = 0
t_N = 5
N = 10000
freq = N/(t_N-t_0)
w_1 = 1
w_2 = 5
x = np.linspace(t_0,t_N,N)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*w_1*x) + np.sin(2*np.pi*w_2*x) + \
    0.05*np.random.randn(x.shape[0])
```

This is the time signal

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('signal')
```

[image: time signal]

The PSD

```
f,p = welch(y,fs=freq,nperseg=2**13)
plt.plot(f,p, '-*')
plt.xlim([0,10])
plt.xlabel('f [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD')
```

[image: PSD]

My integration function

```
def psd_integrate(f, p, f0, fN):
    k0, = np.where(f >= f0) # tuple unpack
    k0 = k0[0] # get 1st index
    kN, = np.where(f <= fN) # tuple unpack
    kN = kN[-1] # get last index
    return simpson(p[k0:kN], f[k0:kN])
```

EDIT: Forgot to add. I'm using `seaborn`, that's why the plots looks different from default `matplotlib`